# Create columns values based on columns names from another two seperate dataframe in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas Dataframe and I want to be able to create the Result column (yellow) by matching column1 values in first df with the appropriate values from the second df. Column1 values in df one are all references to columns names in the second df.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) your first data frame to get same structure as the second data frame. Once you've achieved this, you can do a simple [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Comment: @pansen I thought about that but I want to keep the format of the first df, I'm now trying to pivot the second df

Comment: You can create a temporary df for merging only while keeping your original df. However, reshaping your second df is totally fine as well. In this case, [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) is your friend :-).

Comment: @pansen amazing melt is exactly what I was looking for thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) are a good approach here:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['12/30/2016', '12/30/2016', '1/31/2017', '1/31/2017'], 
                    'Column1': ['APB', 'UPB', 'APB', 'UPB']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['12/30/2016', '1/31/2017', '2/28/2017', '3/31/2017'], 
                   'APB': [117, 112.8, 112.37, 112.23], 
                   'UPB': [67.925, 67.865, 66.717, 66.939]})

melted = pd.melt(df2, id_vars="Date", var_name="Column1", value_name="Result")
merged = df1.merge(melted, on=["Date", "Column1"])

print(merged)

  Column1        Date   Result
0     APB  12/30/2016  117.000
1     UPB  12/30/2016   67.925
2     APB   1/31/2017  112.800
3     UPB   1/31/2017   67.865
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use melt and set_index on your df2

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['12/30/2016', '12/30/2016', '1/31/2017', '1/31/2017'], 'col1': ['APB', 'UPB', 'APB', 'UPB']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['12/30/2016', '1/31/2017', '2/28/2017', '3/31/2017'], 'APB': [117, 112.8, 112.37, 112.23], 'UPB': [67.9, 67.8, 66.7, 66.9]})



df2 = pd.melt(df2, id_vars='Date', value_vars=['APB', 'UPB'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2.sort_values(by = 'Date').set_index('Date')
```

This gives you

```
    variable    value
Date        
2016-12-30  APB 117.00
2016-12-30  UPB 67.90
2017-01-31  APB 112.80
2017-01-31  UPB 67.80
2017-02-28  APB 112.37
```

Now you can merge the two dataframes,

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on = 'col1', right_on = 'variable').drop_duplicates().drop('variable', axis = 1).sort_values(by = 'Date')
```

That gives you

```
    col1    Date    value
0   APB 2016-12-30  117.00
8   UPB 2016-12-30  67.90
1   APB 2017-01-31  112.80
9   UPB 2017-01-31  67.80
2   APB 2017-02-28  112.37
10  UPB 2017-02-28  66.70
3   APB 2017-03-31  112.23
11  UPB 2017-03-31  66.90
```